# Routing Issue for Model that Rails Can't Determine Word Roots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a model named `Faq` and it looks like Rails is having a hard time with the dynamic paths generated from `resources :faq`.

Here is what `rake routes` puts out.

```
   admin_faq_index GET    /admin/faq(.:format)                                   admin/faq#index
                   POST   /admin/faq(.:format)                                   admin/faq#create
     new_admin_faq GET    /admin/faq/new(.:format)                               admin/faq#new
    edit_admin_faq GET    /admin/faq/:id/edit(.:format)                          admin/faq#edit
         admin_faq GET    /admin/faq/:id(.:format)                               admin/faq#show
                   PUT    /admin/faq/:id(.:format)                               admin/faq#update
                   DELETE /admin/faq/:id(.:format)                               admin/faq#destroy
```

The problem is when I use `form_for` like so:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @faq]) do |f| %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `admin_faqs_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdda4627a58>:0x007fdda41a5098>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing routes.rb to

```
resources :faqs
```

Then verify that @faq is not nil.

Based on the fact that you're using a form, I'm guessing your FAQ is not a singular resource.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add an excpetion in `config/initializers/inflector.rb`

like this one

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w(faq)
end
```

It add an exception to pluralize and inflector rules of rails

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cf5bcf7fa85e106640152f717b3af6f9eeba2463 Seems to be linked to that -_-

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in routes `resources :faq` , it has not generate the routes `admin_faqs_path` but in the `form_for` by default it is searching for the `admin_faqs_path`. So we need to override it. Please change the code to

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @faq], :url => admin_faq_index_path, :method => :post) do |f| %>
```